# jq: Select inputs if the string starts with any of an array of strings

Tags: cmake, jq

I'm doing some more work with a cmake ccdb file (compile_commands.json) and am looking to be able to select all of the entries based upon the file in each entry starting with a path from a list of desired root paths I've gleaned from other parsing of the same cmake ccdb.

Here is a sample compile_commands.json for reference:

```
[
  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 -o src/lib/X_core1/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/A.c.o -c src/lib/A.c",
     "file": "src/libAlpha/A.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Y1 -o src/lib/X_core2/CMakeFiles/Y_core.dir/src/A.c.o -c src/lib/A.c",
     "file": "src/libBeta/A.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO -o src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/A.c.o -c src/lib/A.c",
     "file": "src/libGamma/A.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO -o src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/B.c.o -c src/lib/B.c",
     "file": "src/lib/B.c"

  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 -o src/lib/X_core/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/B.c.o -c src/lib/B.c",
     "file": "src/lib/B.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO -o src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/C.c.o -c src/lib/C.c",
     "file": "src/lib/C.c"
  }
]
```

I've got a module with a function already that selects the paths with some criteria from the main input, and I was thinking I'd be using the `... as $identifier` syntax to store that list of paths for comparison using `any()` as well.  But since I'm effectively using an array to filter an array, I'm not quite sure what that syntax looks like.

My first inclination was something like the following, where `main_target_path_array` produces the array of strings to match against:

```
main_target_path_array as $mainpaths |
    map(select(
        any( .file | startswith($mainpaths) )
    ))
```

Clearly, startswith isn't going to like an array argument, but I was hoping it might be smart enough to iterate it.

(For simplicity, you can assume main_target_path_array produces the following array for selecting the files from the compile_commands.json sample above:

```
["src/libAlpha/","src/libBeta/","src/libGamma/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter the entries in the compile_commands.json file based on whether the file path starts with any of the paths in the main_target_path_array, you can use the contains function with the any function as follows:

```
main_target_path_array as $mainpaths |
    map(select(.file | any($mainpaths[]; startswith(.))))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did you mean startswith() instead of contains()?  Also, as written I wind up with the same list of files.  I tried this in a [jqplay snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/IkLHsp6CWs3), but seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which closely matches the problem statement:

```
["src/libAlpha/","src/libBeta/","src/libGamma/"] as $main_target_path
| .[]
| select( .file as $file | any($main_target_path[]; . as $match | $file | startswith($match)))
```

Here are two variants:

```
["src/libAlpha/","src/libBeta/","src/libGamma/"] as $main_target_path
| .[]
| select( .file as $file | $main_target_path | any( . as $match | $file | startswith($match)))
```

```
["src/libAlpha/","src/libBeta/","src/libGamma/"] as $main_target_path
| .[]
| select( any (.file; startswith($main_target_path[] )))
```